# After upgrade Android on Nexus to 4.2.2, Eclipse shows target unknown for device?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just upgraded my phone to 4.2.2, but now i cannot use it in eclipse anymore.

[image]

I tried rebooting the device, reset my debug-settings but I cannot get it to work anymore.

I saw it is already a registered [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=50627). There are some new security enhancements, so there should be a dialog (see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/02/security-enhancements-in-jelly-bean.html) at bottom) but this dialog doesn't appear. I don't have several accounts on the phone, which is pointed out in the issue..

Anyone any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Look at accepted answer below, this should cover all cases. In my case, there were some packages missing, which weren't shown in the Android SDK Manager. I just found the **Packages -> Reload** in the **Android SDK Manager**... And I thought this happens automatically

Comment: I know this problem. In my case it was a broken usb cable. Did you allow debugging in the owner profile?

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest SDK platform-tools, from the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need three things in order to make sure this update goes smoothly:

1. Make sure your device is actually running 4.2.2 and the problem is not something else
2. Your SDK is updated to the latest tools. The `adb` binary in all but the latest version does not support the 4.2.2 security enhancements.
3. You are on the main account of your device in case of multiple user accounts.

Connect your Device to your computer and execute `adb devices` (make sure USB debugging is enabled). You should see something like this:

```
3tiu52839ry082j3 offline
```

Right about now, there should be a dialog on your device that looks something like:

[image]

Check the `Always allow from this computer` box if you want and click `OK`.

That's about it.

Some other things to check:

- Make sure your USB cable isn't broken. Sometimes, the smaller cables break inside the main one, and your device may charge but have no data connection. Try with a different cable, or try accessing files on the device over USB (this will go fine if your cable is fine)
- Make sure you're using the newest version of `adb`. Even after I updated my SDK tools, I couldn't get my device authorized when using `adb`. I eventually figured out that the Nvidia install of the NDK and SDK tools had updated my `PATH` variable to use the `adb` from that install, which wasn't the latest update. By using the `adb` in my newly updated install, I was able to get it all working.

Comment: Great answer. And how did you know it's a Nexus  :-)

Comment: In my case, some packages for API 17 were missing, because they only showed up after reloading the packages in the SDK Manager manually! I expected the packages to be reloading every time, but, well...

Comment: @LaiVung He mentioned it in his post. Plus, only Nexuses (Nexii?) have 4.2.2 as of now :-)

Comment: @longilong yeah that's a bit counter intuitive. Glad you got it fixed!

Comment: @RaghavSood, What do you mean by "smaller cables break inside the main one"?

Answer (score 10):

For me it was solved by changing Nexus 7 tablet to "Camera(PTP)" mode.
Check out [this blog post](http://zacktutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/08/nexus7-android-development.html) on how to do it.
After USB connection of Nexus 7 and confirming digest on Nexus 7, also connecting through TCP/IP with ADB worked.

Answer (score 3):

Wierdly, unchecking and rechecking the "Allow USB Debugging" option popped me the window and selecting "ok" solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the solutions worked for you then Reset ADB.
Go to Devices ---Click the right most down arrow----Select Reset ADB from the list.

Comment: I tried all of the other suggestions and finally this worked for me! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had tried everything suggested here and suggested in every log/blog that I could find in google, but still no go. The USB cable is known to be good. ADB is version 1.0.31 (as shown with , USB Debugging is enabled in the Nexus 7 tablet, the SDK was updated to the very latest tools as available on 1-mar-2013 for 4.2.2/API 17. I had tried both Media and Camera modes for USB, rebooted windows, rebooted device over and over again, re-installed latest google USB driver, etc. etc. but ADB Devices still showed *nothing*.

I hard reset the Nexus 7 tablet thinking that maybe the screen to allow usb debugging had appeared but got hit with cancel. But that didn't work either.

What finally worked was:

1. going into windows control panel | Device Manager,
2. selecting NEXUS under Portable devices,
3. then in the Driver tab clicking on update and manually selecting the Google USB driver (the check feature said it was up to date). Previously, the date shown was in 2006, afterwards a date in 2012 (but more on this in a moment).

That didn't fix anything though.

So then I switched USB from MEDIA device to Camera device - THEN it wanted to install driver software, so I let it do that. Afterwards, I noticed that the driver for the Nexus was back with the 2006 version, BUT then ADB DEVICES FINALLY SHOWED OFFLINE!!!!  HALLELUJAH AND the Nexus was displaying the Dialog to allow USB debugging, and it now all works.

What I am not sure of is what step actually solved the problem. I don't think it was necessary to hard reset the Tablet, but the fiddling with the device driver wasn't a very convincing solution either - I don't think the driver was corrupt - but maybe it had to be changed to get the right driver associated with the tablet when connected as a Camera Device. In any event, it is necessary to connect the tablet as a Camera device for ADB to work...

Answer (score 1):

Restarting device or enabling USB debugging did not solve my problem.
However I changed USB PC Connection to "Camera(PTP)" mode and adb devices showed the device id of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot post talking about this particular problem, I actually solved it by resetting user permissions on files (that were owned by root): ${HOME}/.android/adbkey and ${HOME}/.android/adbkey.pub

Answer (score 0):

Go to Device Manager and uninstall your device and remove from USB
HAve you CMD opend and make sure you are at least in ADB Help.
Connect device to USB and continue with steps provided by Raghav Sood - few answers ahead of me.

Worked for me just fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this custom build and it works for me. Now I can see my logcat in Eclipse again.

https://github.com/khaledev/ADT/releases

Download the zip file then in Eclipse menu Help > Install New Software... > Add > Archive... Just pick the downloaded zip and do the rest of the install process.