# Android 4.2.2 adb can't find devices

Tags: android, adb, nexus-7

With the new update to 4.2.2 to my Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7, I can't find both my devices under `adb`.

These are the steps I took:

- Updated to 4.2.2
- Updated ADT and SDK through the SDK Manager
- Checked ADB version, it's at 1.0.31
- Restarted PC and Tablet and Phone numerous times

When I run `adb devices`, it's just blank. I have the same issue on Windows 8 and on Ubuntu 12.10, but on Ubuntu it shows my device and it says `offline`.

Are there any other steps I can take?

Comment: To be clear, is "Enable USB debugging" still checked?

Comment: Have you installed the USB driver or some sort of pc suite of your nexus devices? Example samsung kies for Samsung devices.

Comment: Maybe this will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031411/after-upgrade-android-on-nexus-to-4-2-2-eclipse-shows-target-unknown-for-device

Comment: It's all stated in my question. I'm using Nexus devices, so no other drivers than from SDK manager. It all worked when still on 4.2.1, but with all the updates to android/adt/adb, I don't know which one I did wrong. @TronicZomB i don't even see the devices as `offline` on Windows, and on Ubuntu, I can't see that pop up window.

Comment: A few readers might find useful to be reminded that USB debugging has to be enable, and [how to enable developper tools](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/73438) when they're not (at least on CyanogenMod).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try pre-installing the drivers for your devices. Make sure, under Windows, that your device is recognized in the System control panel first.

I use Windows 7 and my Galaxy Nexus wouldn't be recognized by the system until I installed the device drivers before plugging them in. From the comments, this works on Windows 8 as well.

Galaxy Nexus drivers

- http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW#
- Goto Manual & Drivers > Software

Nexus 7

- http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus+7&p=28&s=2

Comment: Somehow, my drivers got unloaded? It showed up as a Nexus 7, but it had an exclamation mark next to it. It always worked though... I installed that driver and now it worked. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me when trying to get Windows 8 recognize my Galaxy Nexus

Comment: This is the second time that it happend to me that my devices, which were working normlly dont come up on "adb devices" listing. I restarted the windows 8 machine and device both, and at last I found that under device manager it is coming with a exclamation mark and disabled. I just right clicked on it and enabled it and it worked.

Answer (score 16):

From the [adb docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

> When you connect a device running Android 4.2.2 or higher to your
>   computer, the system shows a dialog asking whether to accept an RSA
>   key that allows debugging through this computer. This security
>   mechanism protects user devices because it ensures that USB debugging
>   and other adb commands cannot be executed unless you're able to unlock
>   the device and acknowledge the dialog. This requires that you have adb
>   version 1.0.31 (available with SDK Platform-tools r16.0.1 and higher)
>   in order to debug on a device running Android 4.2.2 or higher

So,  unplug, wait, replug in the cable, and hit ok (on modal dialog that appears on your device)

If you hit cancel, the device will show up as offline via `adb devices`

Comment: not sure why either,  however,  I had the same issue for about 2minutes before I was able to get the modal RSA fingerprints dialog to appear again.  I had missed it the first time.  This was a nexus 10.  My GNexus is VZ so...no 4.2 goodness for me

Comment: Yes I have been banging my head for the last 3 days... But I fixed it with the answer below. Somehow, something happened to my drivers.

Comment: Unplugging the cord to the device can help if you have updated your udev rules.

Answer (score 12):

Just though Id share my experience, I had -

- Unplugged and re plugged in the device
- Installed the correct platform tools
- Installed the correct Android bridge Turned USB debugging on and off
  and on and off an...
- Tried WiFi but it said it was offline
- etc. etc.

What fixed it for me was changing the device connection from Mass Storage to MTP. To do so, with the phone unplugged you go into -

> "Settings" -> "Storage" -> *Click the menu Button* -> "USB computer
>   connection" -> "Media device (MTP)"

Hope this helps some one from going crazy!

Thanks,

Ash.

Comment: This needs to be the top comment. I've been struggling with CyanogenMod debugging and was going crazy, turns out this finally did it to me.

Comment: A variant of this fixed it for me. I had to turn *off* MTP, and then it started working immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything mentioned here and in other posts.  It wasn't the cable, the USB port, rebooting the PC or Nexus 7, killing and starting adb or enabling/disabling USB Debugging.

It was due to the 4.2.2 OTA update, I simply replaced the \platform-tools\ folder, as described here: [Android ADB device offline, can't issue commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993855/android-adb-device-offline-cant-issue-commands)

Download the updated platform-tools: http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r16.0.1-windows.zip

Answer (score 2):

adb wait-for-device

works for me. Just unplug your usb device, run this command, and while it's waiting, plug your device in, then it will just work. :)

Comment: I did this for several times, finally my Nueus7 shows dialog and ask me to allow USB debugging, and it become online in eclipse...

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did (Galaxy S4 4.2.2):

- go to Settings => about this device => click several times on "Version number", that is to say something like "JDQ39.I9505XXBHYTGKDD" (not android version or anything else) ; here you will see that Google or Samsung have a lot of humour as you have to click until multiple times until having a toast displaying "You are at few clicks from being a developer" ; after something like 10 clicks, you have a toast "You are a developer"
- Go "Development options" (in the "More" tab (rigjt tab of settings menu)) ; be sure that "USB debugging" is checked.

And it works ! Eclipse can see your S4(or any other device) 4.2.2 !

Comment: Here is a graphical description of how to do this: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57549207-285/restore-the-developer-options-menu-in-android-4.2/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and fixed it by rebooting the Tab2 while leaving it plugged into the laptop/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed android-adb-tools in Ubuntu. If you do, the adb tool may be old. Uninstall and make an alias to the latest adb tool you download with the ADB plugin. To check the adb version do "adb version" if it's 1.0.29 is the old, the latest and working for Android 4.2.2 is 1.0.31.

I made a lot of stuff until i realized this.

Comment: if you read the steps I took in my question: `Checked ADB version, it's at 1.0.31`, I already did that ;). But I had not uninstalled it and then do an alias.

Answer (score 0):

going to Developer Options and checking USB Debugging solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

My solution used on cm10.1 nightly build on droid bionic, was after updating the newest usb drivers, using the Mass storage option  (instead of the MTP option for USB computer connection), then unchecking and rechecking in developer options, "ADB over network" option. Then it did the RSA pop up dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution was:

Update the Android SDK via the SDK-Manager. Removing the '.android' folder in my usr directory ( Windows 7 ) and re-plugging the device back in.  Worked flawlessly due to the ADB RSA key issue. I had an older version of ADB that I stashed into c:\windows\system32\ due to not wanting to install an entire freakin SDK when all I wanted was a command prompt. Good ol' Google, the new Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an old version of adb.exe. Update platform-tools.
You may have to set a new path to adb.exe as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else arriving here, I had this problem with a ZTE phone.

I tried installing the driver based on the offical list [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) but in Device Manager the driver was marked as not installed correctly.

In the end I found the way to make this work was:

1. Press Menu Button
2. Choose "Connect to PC"
3. Choose "Default connect type"
4. Choose "Install Driver"
5. Plug in phone and on PC select option to install the driver
6. Then change "Default connect type" to "PC software"

After doing this I was able to do:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

and view my device.

Answer (score -1):

It's working on windows 8 using Android 4.4.2

Reset your phone,

- go to setting->about phone-> seven time click on build number.
- go to back and go to developer options check USB debugging.
- go to windows 8 start menu click on profile picture and click change profile picture.

Select devices and on Download over metered connections.
Connect your phone via cable your PC and wait.