# Eclipse cannot find my android 4.1.2 device

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to run just the intro "Hello World!" app on my phone (Droid Razr Maxx) which is running android 4.1.2 jelly bean using Eclipse. I have USB Debugging enabled, have tried updating the drivers/reinstalling the drivers for my phone (I have the Google USB driver also), and have tried changing the type of device the computer reads it as from mass storage to media device to camera. Restarts haven't been working for anything (computer, eclipse, phone, meh). When I go to look for my device it doesn't even show up, the form is blank: [pic of Android Device Chooser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyZKj.jpg). Any clue as to what may be happening?

Comment: checkout this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033218/android-4-2-2-adb-cant-find-devices/15033277#15033277

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the Motorola device manager. With this the driver of your phone will be installed, i was having the same issue you have with Motorola devices. You can download the device manager from here: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the drivers installed correctly and your computer reads your phone as an external device, I would recommend enabling "Unknown Sources" or something to that affect in the *Security* section of your Settings.

Also, for some reason when I was researching this stuff about my S3, I was told to enable "Stay Awake", which can be found in the *Developer Options* section of your Settings.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check [HERE](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) for installation of your mobile driver.
[ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) should detect your device, to check this, open window `command prompt` change directory to `android sdk` folder by `cd` command, then go to `platform-tools` then this command `adb kill-server` then `adb devices`.

Answer (score -1):

Unplug the Device from your Computer.On your handset, go to Settings then click on Security. Make sure the Unknown sources checkbox is ticked. Go back. Scroll down to Developer Options. Make sure the USB Debugging and allow mock locations is ticked. 
Re-plug your Device back to your computer. It should find your Device now.