# Can't Select Device for debugging

Tags: android, debugging, ide, nexus-7

I have updated my android version from 4.1.1 to 4.2.2 on google Nexus 7, (Worked Perfect Before)After that unfortunately i can't debug my App anymore,i can see my device on "Android Device Chooser" page but i can't select it, and ok button is not Active. my minsdk version is 12 and in that page written that "Select a device compatible with Target android 3.1"!.i'm developing on Motodev Studio, i'm working on this for hours but i don't know what causes this issue ,any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031411/after-upgrade-android-on-nexus-to-4-2-2-eclipse-shows-target-unknown-for-device)

there were some packages missing, which weren't shown in the Android SDK Manager,so after reload on Sdk manager and installing missing packages my problem had been solved!