# Turning on developer options on Galaxy S4

Tags: android, galaxy

How do you turn on developer options (debug, adb, etc) for the Samsung Galaxy S4?

Comment: No, using the phone. It doesn't have a section for 'dev options' like its predecessors, and other Android phones.

Comment: Why the close votes?  This is without question a development question!

Comment: This is NOT off topic. From the http://stackoverflow.com/faq `We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
   ...
    software tools commonly used by programmers
...
if this isn't used by dev's, I don't know what is.

Comment: This isn't off-topic.  It's NARQ.  It shows **zero** research.  This question is answerable within five seconds in any search engine.

Comment: So just because you can find it somewhere else, means that it can't be posted here for others?

Comment: @Blaine - exactly.  The off-topic closure is incorrect. The only legitimate reason for closing it would be if it can be marked as a duplicate of another question here.

Comment: Which it can't, and isn't.

Comment: fyi I just googled "android s4 developer settings" and this was the top hit - mods are being overly zealous imho. please lets reopen this

Comment: Thank you Richard! When I searched, I found answers, but figured this would be a great place to list the answer as well. You can also vote to reopen, & vote for the question, with the hope others will vote as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Go to – Settings > About phone.
- Then move on to `Build number` option
- Tap on Build number repeatedly 7 times.
- This is enough.
- After touching 7th time you will see a message that, “You are now a developer”.

Now you'll have developer options under the System heading, from where you can enable USB Debugging etc.

Also make sure you're running the latest tools on your computer, as 4.2.2 onwards you have to verify the RSA key for ADB. This is not available unless you are running the latest version of ADT, and your device will appear offline when connected if you're using an older version.

References: [Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-get-developer-settings-galaxy-s4), [Haptic Antics](http://blog.immersion.com/2013/05/developer-options-galaxy-s4/)

Comment: This looks like an elaborate joke answer, so here are references to confirm it: 1. [Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-get-developer-settings-galaxy-s4) 2. [Haptic Antics](http://blog.immersion.com/2013/05/developer-options-galaxy-s4/).

Comment: @BilltheLizard Haha just noticed that :P Been working on Android too long to think of what it'd look like to others. Editing the links you gave into the answer itself

Comment: Thx for the update, I was just noticing that I kept getting 'device offline'. Great answer!

Comment: I have the latest version of tools (22.0.1) and the device is still showing offline. Any idea why?

Comment: @Blaine When you plugin the device and enable USB debugging, you should follow the steps given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031663/1069068) (for the Nexus 7, but they should still work)