# Eclipse do not recognize android 4.2 (galaxy mini 2)

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio, firmware

I have upgraded my android api 7 (samsung galaxy mini 2/ GT-S6500D) to android 4.2.2 CyanogeMod 10.1, after what my android studio(4.2) under ubuntu (12.04_x64) stopped detecting it. When plug it to PC system detects phone and sd as:

```
Name: Internal storage/SD card
Type: folder (inode/directory)
Contents: ...
Location: mtp://[usb:003,007]/
Volume: mtp
Free space:  ..GB
```

Does anybody faced similar problem and has any sollution for this?

When I leave open windows it whole time shows:
[image]

trying to kill and start server do not change anything.
After every server start when I run `./adb devices` it gives empty list:

```
List of devices attached 
[nothing here...]
```

Is it normal that it is launched in `Location: mtp://[usb:003,007]/` ?

For more.. after upgrade it detects SIM card: SIM CARD IS LOCKED. - EMERGENCY CALLS ONLY

And when I plug phone to PC it shows:
[image]

And before there was something like dialog box with "select what to do?".

Comment: had a similar issue months agos, maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031411/after-upgrade-android-on-nexus-to-4-2-2-eclipse-shows-target-unknown-for-device

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031663/1562755

Answer (score 0):

go to ur command prompt `kill ur ADB` and then `start ADB` it will detect ur device

go to ur command line tool,,

```
cd <android-sdk/platfromtools>
```

then,,

```
./adb kill-server
```

then,,

```
sudo ./adb start-server
```

it will show ur device

Comment: go to ur eclipse,,while running application it will prompt u to pick device,,,let the device box just be there on screen,,open ur command line tool sid and try 4 to 5 times ,check each time in device box it will come

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when our Galaxy Tab 2 devices got the latest update to 4.2.2 (I think they've got 4.1.x beforehand). The device turned up in eclipse but only as "unknown" type with a random string as name..

I tried the above but it did not work. After that I just tried

```
    adb get-serialno  //or
    adb get-state
```

Then the question on the device if the computer should be allowed to have debugging access came and after acknowledging it the devicename changed in eclipse.

I don't know if this has to be done at any disconnect/reconnect of the USB again or not.
This is just a workaround, let's hope that it gets better with next eclipse or samsung update..