# Android 4.3 Eclipse Android Device Chooser states version unknown

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I recently upgraded my Samsung Galaxy Nexus via an OTA update to 4.3. After doing the update, I am unable to install new debug software, because the "Target" is set to UNKNOWN. I have tried the following tricks that have been shown to work:

1. Reboot phone
2. Turn on/off debugging on phone
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Updating SDK tools (Both ADT and plugin)

I never had this problem when I was with 4.2, so I suspect is has something to do with the upgrade, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031411/after-upgrade-android-on-nexus-to-4-2-2-eclipse-shows-target-unknown-for-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out a combination of things did the trick.

1. On the device, go to the debug options (Debug activity in notifications)
2. Revoke USB debugging information
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Look for a pop-up on the device asking for permission to connect to the device. Give it permission.

That seemed to do the trick.